# Inject ECS Task ARN into AWS Cloudwatch Event Rule using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to create an AWS Cloudwatch event rule to send SNS email notifications when a container running a particular task finishes running successfully. I have scoured through the Terraform documentation, but can't find a good way to dynamically inject in the `taskArn`:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "important-task-complete-rule" {
  name = "reporting-task-completed"
  description = "Notification for when an important task finishes running successfully."

  event_pattern = <<PATTERN
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ecs"
    ],
  "detail-type": [
    "ECS Task State Change"
    ],
  "detail": {

    "lastStatus": [
      "STOPPED"
    ],
"stoppedReason" : [
    "Essential container in task exited"
  ],
"containers": {
  "exitCode": [
        0
      ],
  "taskArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:MY_ACCOUNT:task/MY_TASK_ID_THAT_I_WANT_TO_INJECT"
    }
}
}
PATTERN
}
```

For example, the [documentation examples](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_event_rule.html) here provide the same hardcoded `<<PATTERN` example I am using above.

Is there a template file way to dynamically insert in my ARNs without having them be hardcoded in?

Comment: You can use variables in that inlined JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @matt Schuchard said, did you manage it with [terraform resource attributes?](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ecs_task_definition.html#attributes-reference) (By the way, it is not called `variables`).

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "service" {
   ...
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "important-task-complete-rule" {
  name = "reporting-task-completed"
  description = "Notification for when an important task finishes running successfully."

  event_pattern = <<PATTERN
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ecs"
    ],
  "detail-type": [
    "ECS Task State Change"
    ],
  "detail": {

    "lastStatus": [
      "STOPPED"
    ],
"stoppedReason" : [
    "Essential container in task exited"
  ],
"containers": {
  "exitCode": [
        0
      ],
  "taskArn": "${aws_ecs_task_definition.service.arn}"
    }
}
}
PATTERN
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked as expected. I used an inline JSON template.